# How to keyframe Force Field On/Off?

Tags: animation, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, force-fields

I want to make a rigid body simulation using a bunch of particles falling down on a plane then be lifted up using a Wind Force (after being grouped up using Vortex)

I tried with the following :

-Keyframing Disable in viewport at frame 0 and frame 90

-Keyframing Enable in viewport at frame 91

[image]

It resulted in the rigid body objects not being affected by the force even after turning it on

NB: I tried keyframing the strength of the force instead but that resulted in a slower simulation at the start.

**EDIT**: I want the particles to fall into the plane THEN get picked up by the force field.
Keyframing the strength value (0 at start/-10 at frame 90) of the Vortex makes the objects fall in a weird fashion.

**TO ANYONE WHO WANTS TO GIVE IT A TRY** : [image]

[image]

Comment: i have no idea what you meant with "slower simulation at the start" but keyframing the strength is the way to go. Maybe you should show us an animation (post a link in your question) how it should look like.

Comment: I uploaded the blend and the result

Comment: i still don't know how you want the whole simulation to look like? do you have a link to an yt video? or some other link? And maybe the wind isn't even the right thing. Sometimes an "invisible" plane as passive rigid body object to make them move might be even better...e.g. like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjyqQ.gif describing animations with words lets a lot of freedom how it should look - that's the problem.